# Optimising php scripts for memory usage rather than increasing php memory_limit in php.ini

Tags: php, optimization, memory-leaks

```
<?php

class diff {

  var $changes = array();
  var $diff = array();
  var $linepadding = null;

  function doDiff($old, $new) {
    if (!is_array($old))
      $old = file($old);
    if (!is_array($new))
      $new = file($new);

    $maxlen = 0;

    foreach ($old as $oindex => $ovalue) {
      $nkeys = array_keys($new, $ovalue);
      foreach ($nkeys as $nindex) {
        $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ? $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
        if ($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen) {
          $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
          $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
          $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
        }
      }
    }
    if ($maxlen == 0)
      return array(array('d' => $old, 'i' => $new));

    return array_merge(
            $this->doDiff(array_slice($old, 0, $omax), array_slice($new, 0, $nmax)), array_slice($new, $nmax, $maxlen), $this->doDiff(array_slice($old, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($new, $nmax + $maxlen)));
  }

  function diffWrap($old, $new) {
    $this->diff = $this->doDiff($old, $new);
    $this->changes = array();
    $ndiff = array();
    foreach ($this->diff as $line => $k) {
      if (is_array($k)) {
        if (isset($k['d'][0]) || isset($k['i'][0])) {
          $this->changes[] = $line;
          $ndiff[$line] = $k;
        }
      } else {
        $ndiff[$line] = $k;
      }
    }
    $this->diff = $ndiff;
    return $this->diff;
  }

  function formatcode($code) {
    $code = htmlentities($code);
    $code = str_replace(" ", '&nbsp;', $code);
    $code = str_replace("\t", '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $code);
    return $code;
  }

  function showline($line) {
    if ($this->linepadding === 0) {
      if (in_array($line, $this->changes))
        return true;
      return false;
    }
    if (is_null($this->linepadding))
      return true;

    $start = (($line - $this->linepadding) > 0) ? ($line - $this->linepadding) : 0;
    $end = ($line + $this->linepadding);
    //echo '<br />'.$line.': '.$start.': '.$end;
    $search = range($start, $end);
    //pr($search);
    foreach ($search as $k) {
      if (in_array($k, $this->changes))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function inline($old, $new, $linepadding = null) {

// get device details by exloding device path passed over to method
    $device_a_pathArr = explode("/", $old);
    $device_b_pathArr = explode("/", $new);

// $device_a (Old) details
    $device_a_Name = $device_a_pathArr['5'];
    $device_a_Date = $device_a_pathArr['8'] . " " . $device_a_pathArr['7'] . " " . $device_a_pathArr['6'];
    $device_a_File = $device_a_pathArr['9'];

// $device_b (New) details
    $device_b_Name = $device_b_pathArr['5'];
    $device_b_Date = $device_b_pathArr['8'] . " " . $device_b_pathArr['7'] . " " . $device_b_pathArr['6'];
    $device_b_File = $device_b_pathArr['9'];

    $this->linepadding = $linepadding;

    $ret = '<pre>
            <table width="75%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="code">';
    $ret.= '<tr>
              <td>Line</td>
              <td style="padding-left:20px;"><font size="2"><b>Device:' . $device_a_Name . '</b><font> Date:' . $device_a_Date . ' FileName:' . $device_a_File . ' </td>
              <td>Line</td>
              <td style="padding-left:20px;"><font size="2"><b>Device:' . $device_b_Name . '</b><font> Date:' . $device_b_Date . ' FileName:' . $device_b_File . ' </td>
             </tr>';
    $count_old = 1;
    $count_new = 1;

    $insert = false;
    $delete = false;
    $truncate = false;

    $diff = $this->diffWrap($old, $new);

    foreach ($diff as $line => $k) {
      if ($this->showline($line)) {
        $truncate = false;
        if (is_array($k)) {
          foreach ($k['d'] as $val) {
            $class = '';
            if (!$delete) {
              $delete = true;
              $class = 'first';
              if ($insert)
                $class = '';
              $insert = false;
            }
            $ret.= '<tr><th>' . $count_old . '</th>';
            $ret.= '<td class="del ' . $class . '">' . $this->formatcode($val) . '</td>';
            $ret.= '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
            $ret.= '<td class="truncated ' . $class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
            $ret.= '</tr>';
            $count_old++;
          }
          foreach ($k['i'] as $val) {
            $class = '';
            if (!$insert) {
              $insert = true;
              $class = 'first';
              if ($delete)
                $class = '';
              $delete = false;
            }
            $ret.= '<tr><th>&nbsp;</th>';
            $ret.= '<td class="truncated ' . $class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
            $ret.= '<th>' . $count_new . '</th>';
            $ret.= '<td class="ins ' . $class . '">' . $this->formatcode($val) . '</td>';
            $ret.= '</tr>';
            $count_new++;
          }
        } else {
          $class = ($delete) ? 'del_end' : '';
          $class = ($insert) ? 'ins_end' : $class;
          $delete = false;
          $insert = false;
          $ret.= '<tr><th>' . $count_old . '</th>';
          $ret.= '<td class="' . $class . '">' . $this->formatcode($k) . '</td>';
          $ret.= '<th>' . $count_new . '</th>';
          $ret.= '<td class="' . $class . '">' . $this->formatcode($k) . '</td>';
          $ret.= '</tr>';
          $count_old++;
          $count_new++;
        }
      } else {
        $class = ($delete) ? 'del_end' : '';
        $class = ($insert) ? 'ins_end' : $class;
        $delete = false;
        $insert = false;

        if (!$truncate) {
          $truncate = true;
          $ret.= '<tr><th>...</th>';
          $ret.= '<td class="truncated ' . $class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
          $ret.= '<th>...</th>';
          $ret.= '<td class="truncated ' . $class . '">&nbsp;</td>';
          $ret.= '</tr>';
        }
        $count_old++;
        $count_new++;
      }
    }
    $ret.= '</table></pre>';
    return $ret;
  }
}
?>
```

I have been reading about gabarge collection in php ,but everything seems a bit confusing right now.The above script comapares 2 files for differences and its working ok for files that are less than 168kb to be precise ...... i have one large file that is 168 kb and when you try to compare the 2 files , it complains about memory being exhausted. tried to increase memory in php.ini until it was about 1000M and to me that seems like a poorly written code...... can you help me optimise it

Comment: Recursively calling doDiff() isn't going to be particularly good for memory usage

Comment: hie Mark baker ,im trying to see if i can convert it into an iterative code ,are you able to help get read of the dodiff in the recursive statement.Traced using xdebugger and its definitely stuck on the doDiff() method